# dismisViewController leaks viewcontrollers when first responder set

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiresponder

In my simple navigation style iPhone app, when the user presses a button I am presenting a view controller V1 (modally) using presentViewController.

When the user presses another button this then presents another view controller V2 (modally) using presentViewController.

I then attempt to dismiss both in one go by calling dismissViewController on the root navigation controller and as expected they disappear from the screen :-) However when I log dealloc calls then I see nothing :-(

Through trial and error I tracked the issue down to the fact that in V1 I implement canBecomeFirstResponder == YES. If I change this to NO then everything deallocs properly. It's as though first responder is keeping a reference on the V1. However - when I present V2 I see V1 resign first responder. Indeed, if I don't ever present V2 then V1 will dealloc just fine/

Anyone seen anything like this or know what's going on? I'm on iOS7

[UPDATE: I'm using ARC and it's all in a very simple test app - so no delegates or strong references anywhere.)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Scotty, did you find an answer? I'm having the same issue with navigation controller added as child view controller.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you dismiss V1 first before presenting V2? Then you would only have to dismiss V2 to go back to root.

Comment: Technically I could - but I'm loathed to since it's a valid UI (many of the built in apps present modal view controllers, one on top of the other - mail for example.) The Apple docs also state that it should be possible to dismiss all VCs in one go with dismissViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Call poptorootviewcontroller on navigation controller before you dismiss it.